# Modified Rust Book Guessing Game Query

Tags: error-handling, rust, idioms

I modified the code from the Rust Book's [Guessing Game Tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) to make it a little shorter; for a slide. Alas, I've introduced a bug, and it no longer executes correctly: the first input works as expected, but subsequent entries now yield no feedback.

What is the best way to guard against this situation?

```
use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    let mut guess = String::new();

    loop {
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        println!("You guessed: {}", guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "What is the best way to guard against this situation?" what situation?

Comment: Question has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read_line` will append the line to buffer, so your `guess` will accumulate all the inputs include newline characters! Moving `let mut guess = String::new();` inside the loop solves the problem:

```rust
fn main() {
    ...

    loop {
        let mut guess = String::new();

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it's clearly better to reuse the same memory using `clear()` in this case

Comment: @Stargateur Certainly. But OP is looking for shorter code and it is also more aligned with code in the Rust book. I'd say it is more pedagogically consistent this way.